# Bootstrap carousel moves down when in mobile mode when i press the toggle navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

In `mobile view`, when the `navbar` collapses and i press on the `toggle`, the `navbar` behaves as it should but the `carousel` also moves down along with it. Also there is a `70px gap` between the `navbar and the carousel`, which i used to fix by adding a `negative margin-top` on the `carousel` so it goes up by force, but how do i do this naturally?

Thank you!

Comment: Code: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=yrDx3JCObJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the `position` of your `.carousel` absolute and tweak the `top` value:

```
.carousel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}
```

You can make the `top` of your `.navbar-default` zero or anything by doing this:

```
.navbar-default {
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `carousel` moves down because the navbars height changes to take up more of the screen. The gap between the `carousel` and the `navbar` might be because of padding added to the `<body>` tag, try adding `style="padding-top: 0;"` to the `<body>` tag.

If you could show us your code with [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), that would be helpful to.

Comment: For more on navbars and carousels check bootstraps documentation [Navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar),
[Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)

Comment: Okay, I fixed the spacing error, now it's the first and main one. the navbar taking up more space issue..